# Is Marketing cloud able to capture to whom the subscriber forwarding the email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit, email-tracking, tracking

We have FTAF data view in SFMC to know which subscriber is forwarding the email which was sent via marketing cloud. Can we able to track to whom the Subscriber is forwarding the SFMC email?

Example: SFMC sent an email to Subscriber A. If Subscriber A forwards the email to Person "B". Can we able to capture Person "B" details in Marketing cloud anywhere?

Please help on this.

Comment: Are you using the built in FTAF feature, or hope for the regular forwards (directly from inbox) being captured too? Since the latter will not pass any information back to MC.

Comment: Hi @LukasLunow, I have this question about regular forwards (directly from inbox) . Thank you so much for your answer. It really helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward to a friend (FTAF) is a built in feature in MC, which I am yet to see implemented on any of my projects. It relies on the original recipient accessing a standard preference page in SFMC, providing email addresses on recipients he/she wants the email forwarded to, and SFMC sends then a copy of that email to the provided email addresses. These "forwards" can then be found in [FTAF data view](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_ftaf.htm&type=5).

You will not be able to find any information on me, taking an email received from SFMC and forwarding it to you. Looking at _FTAF data views on multiple accounts also returns zero rows, confirming this.

Comment: Thanks for the info Lukas